# Autorotation in iOS 6 & iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to support the autorotation in iOS 6 and 7. In my project I have a UITabBar with 4 ViewControllers. Only one ViewController of them should support the autorotaion to Portrait and Landscape. The other views should support only the Portrait style.

I hope you have an idea how to implement this function. shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation doesn't work in iOS 7 :(

I added a UITabBarConntroller to control the autorotation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (self.selectedIndex == 1) 
        return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    else 
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Maybe there is a way to change the Orientation manual when the View with the index 1 did disappear??

I hope you have a solution!

Comment: You could define those methods in each view controller, and again place `return self.selectedViewController.shouldAutorotate;` and `self.selectedViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;` in the Tab Bar Controller class. This will retrieve the `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` values from the active view controller and use them for the tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

- Open project
- Go to the General tab
- Under orientation options check all checkbox orientation that you need to support

Go to the implementation of first view controller and add this code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Also for supporting iOS 6 implement method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

Go to all other view controllers that are represented your tabs and set:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

Also for supporting iOS 6 implement method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Check this [link](http://www.sebastianborggrewe.de/only-make-one-single-view-controller-rotate/) as well

Comment: I ve added link check it

Comment: Yes, rotation will not "work", but it will still be possible to switch to a view controller in the "wrong" (i.e. unsupported) interface orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Set the orientations settings like this:
[image]

In UITabBarController:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // You do not need this method if you are not supporting earlier iOS Versions
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (self.selectedViewController) 
        return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This will not work, it will still be possible to open a view controller in an unsupported orientation.

Comment: Is there a way to set one view to Landscape and the other views to portrait without autorotation?